# How would I have different Opacity levels on inner content using Wordpress on different pages?

Tags: css, wordpress, opacity

I have a golf website I am working on where I am using a golf hole background.  To have this so you can see the image on the home page I changed opacity levels down to 70% in CSS on the inner text content.  I don't want it to look like that on other pages so trying to figure out how to do this one of two ways: 1. Only have the golf hole background image on the home page or 2. Have the Opacity level on all other pages besides the homepage at 100%.  I have done a pile of searches and can't find a solution.
[location of site](https://patonplacetestsite2.ca)

Comment: You need to add code to the question, not just a link to your website. Once you fix your website, this question will have no value to future visitors. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Hello I  know this is really old post and I am the one that put it here but just noticed this currently isn't working??  I went back to this to put the snippet in the theme but still does not function.  Any thoughts on what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's actually pretty easy. You're looking at dynamic content display.

They're is multiple ways you can achieve this, let's take a look at one of them:

Taking a look at your website i can see that you added a `opacity:.7;` style to the `.site-inner` class. As the same `style.css` file is loaded on ALL pages, you can't achieve this from here, let's **REMOVE** the `opacity:.7;` from the `style.css`.

Conditional display is achieved using PHP. Sadly we can't use PHP into CSS file... but we can use CSS in a PHP file!

As you want the style of your `.site-inner` class to be different on the index/home page, we're going to open the `header.php` file.

Inside the `header.php` file, in-between the `head` tag you can add the following:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ): ?>
<style media="screen">
.site-inner{opacity:.7!important;}
</style>

<?php else: ?>
<style media="screen">
.site-inner{opacity:1!important;}
</style>

<?php endif; ?>
```

That's it!

We're pretty saying: **"IF the page template is home or front page, then set the opacity for the `.site-inner` class to .7, ELSE set the opacity for the `.site-inner` class to 1."**

**One more thing**:
The opacity style affect the parent container and all children form the affected parent. In your case, the content (text and images) are also affected by the opacity.

I would suggest you to use rgba color code. The rgba color code enable you, by using it with `background-color`, to control only the background color opacity of the container instead of the whole content (childs and parents). For example by using  (`background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5)`), you will get a white background with 50% opacity without affecting the content.

With rgba color code:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ): ?>
<style media="screen">
.site-inner{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7)!important;}
</style>

<?php else: ?>
<style media="screen">
.site-inner{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1)!important;}
</style>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT:** In response to **@ArnaudV**, I don't recommend targeting specific pages with css rules, if you add or remove pages that are affected by a specific targeted css rule, the new page wont be affected by it.

Do not hesitate to tell me if this help you, regards.

Comment: Yeah, I linked to a more proper way to select pages based on classes, but it might be a case where the person is styling using the back-office interface, and no php / templating.

Comment: At the end of the day you're the dev, and it's your project. We all have habits!

Comment: Dont't forget to thumbs up the answer that helped you and check the accepted asnwer checkmark on the left side

Comment: Thank you all for your help this was great and very good points!  I will make the adjustment in the header.php file!

Comment: @PatonPlace don't forget to thumbs up the answer that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see on the link you provided, two important points need to be addressed in order to have it properly working:

**1: Opacity management**

I don't think you should use `opacity` directly on an element containing children, as the opacity will affect the children too. Here, your text also has an opacity of 0.7, which can be not easy to read, and not the intended design. I encourage you for this case to set an opacified color to the `.inner-site` background using this. `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);` `rgba` define colors using the Red-green-blue-alpha model, that allows transparency. `255, 255, 255` is the rgb code for white, and 0.7 the opacity you want.

**2: CSS precision**

You are targeting `.site-inner` in your css, which is present on each of your page. Thus, it gets the same style on all of the pages.
If you want to work correctly with CSS, you should be as precise as possible when targeting element in order to have your style not overlapping areas.

Wordpress provides classes to the body of each page that you could use in order to target specifically your first and second pages. Here, you can use the page ids provided as classes to target

```
.page-id-16 .site-inner,
.page-id-8 .site-inner {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

Page ids are not the best selector because they can change if you create new pages and you would have to hardcode every ids in the future, so I encourage you too look at ways to [give your wordpress page's body a class](https://wpbeaches.com/add-a-different-css-body-class-to-a-page-in-wordpress/).

Edit: more links about adding custom classes to your pages

- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/wordpress-body-class-101-tips-and-tricks-for-theme-designers/
- https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/set-a-wordpress-body-class-using-a-page-slug/